# Is there a densely defined closed operator $A$ such that $codim(D(A))=1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, linear-transformations, spectral-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Is there a closed operator $ A:D(A)\subset X \rightarrow X $
such that $ D(A)\neq \overline{D(A)}=X $ and $ codim (D(A))=1$ ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph $G(A) = \{(x,A(x)) \; : \; x \in D(A)\}$ is a closed subspace of $X^2$.
Take some $w \in X \backslash D(A)$.  Then $G(A) \oplus \text{span}((x,0))$ is a closed subspace of $X^2$ and is the graph of a linear operator $B$.  By the Closed Graph Theorem, $B$ is bounded.   Now
if $x_n \in D(A)$ with $x_n \to w$, we have $(x_n, A(x_n)) \to (w, 0)$, and the assumption that $w \notin D(A)$ contradicts the assumption that $A$ is a closed operator.

Comment: Let $X$ be a Banach space. Is there a closed operator $A:D\left( A\right)
\subset X\rightarrow X$ such that $D\left( A\right) \neq \overline{D\left(
A\right) }$, $D\left( A\right) \cap F=\left\{ 0\right\} $ and $D\left(
A\right) +F=X$ for some closed subspace $F\subset X$ ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2342429/is-there-a-closed-operator-a-and-a-closed-subspace-f-such-that-da-neq-o?noredirect=1#comment4823216_2342429